# do I need to surround fileInputStream.close with a try/catch/finally block? How is it done?

Tags: java, oop, try-catch-finally

I have the following Java Class that does one thing, fires out values from `config.properties`.

When it comes time to close the `fileInputStream`, I think I read on Wikipedia that it is good to have it in a finally block. Because it honestly works just fine in try/catch block.

Can you show me correction to get `fileInputStream.close()` in a finally section?

ConfigProperties.java
    package base;

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConfigProperties {

    public FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    public String property;

    public String getConfigProperties(String strProperty) {

        Properties configProperties = new Properties();
        try {

            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("resources/config.properties");
            configProperties.load(fileInputStream);
            property = configProperties.getProperty(strProperty);
            System.out.println("getConfigProperties(" + strProperty + ")");

            // use a finally block to close your Stream.
            // If an exception occurs, do you want the application to shut down?

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }
        finally {
            fileInputStream.close();
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Is the solution only to do as Eclipse suggests and do this in the finally block?

```
finally {
    try {
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI:  commons-io has a nice function:  IOUtils.closeQuietly() that will take care of the try/catch on the close.  Your code will look much nicer :)  Keep in mind that this function does not give you the chance to respond to the IOException, but usually people don't do that and ignore the exception anyway.  If you need to respond, make your own utility method which logs or prints a stack trace or whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `FileInputStream.close()` throws an IOException, and the finally{} block doesn't catch exceptions. So you need to either catch it or declare it in order to compile. Eclipse's suggestion is fine; catch the IOException inside the finally{} block.

Comment: You can also use the [IOUtils.closeQuietly()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.io.Closeable)) method from Commons IO.  It wraps the close method to drop all of the IOExceptions that are thrown.  Cleaner than having another try/catch block.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, that is the common pre-Java 7 solution. However, with the introduction of Java 7, there are now [`try`-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statements which will automatically close any declared resources when the `try` block exits:

```
try (FileInputStream fileIn = ...) {
    // do something
} // fileIn is closed
catch (IOException e) {
    //handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The standard approach is:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
try {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(...);
    // do something with the inputstream
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle an exception
} finally { //  finally blocks are guaranteed to be executed
    // close() can throw an IOException too, so we got to wrap that too
    try {
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            fileInputStream.close();
        }        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle an exception, or often we just ignore it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good habit to close streams because what it does in background it's called buffering, meaning that it does not free the **internal buffer** and does not free the **file descriptor**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33359338)